# C# merge two lists into one list like Enumerable.ConvertAll

Tags: c#, list, merge, convertall

I want to convert two lists with the same index into a single list.
Given this:

```
List<double> ListA = new List<double> {  1,  2,  3,  4,  5  };
List<string> ListB = new List<string> { "A","B","C","D","E" };
```

until now, I used this:

```
List<string> UNHAPPY = new List<string>();
for (int ListIndex = 0; ListIndex < ListA.Count; ListIndex++)
{
    UNHAPPY.Add(ListB[ListIndex]+ListA[ListIndex].ToString());
}
// such that UNHAPPY == new List<string> {"A1", "B2", "C3", "D4", "E5"}
```

But I really want to use short code as possible, like this (Similar to Enumerable.ConvertAll):

```
List<string> HAPPY = SOME_CONTAINER(ListA, ListB).SOME_SELECTOR((a,b) => b + a.ToString());

// such that HAPPY == new List<string> {"A1", "B2", "C3", "D4", "E5"}
```

Is there any quick method for this? Thank you so mush in advance!

Answer (score 6, accepted):

LINQ has a method for this, it's called [`Zip`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd267698%28v=vs.110%29.aspx?f=255&MSPPError=-2147217396):

```
var res = ListA.Zip(ListB, (a,b) => $"{b}{a}");
```

It takes two sequences and a `Func` delegate, and applies the delegate to pairs of items coming from the two sequences.

**Note:** call of `ToString` on `a` is redundant, C# will concatenate a string to anything, including an `int`, by calling `ToString` on the corresponding object. I prefer string interpolation, especially when you need to concatenate more than two items.

Answer (score 2):

You are looking for `Enumerable.Zip`

```
first.Zip(second, (f, s) => f + s.ToString());
```

Answer (score 2):

You can do this with a [`Zip`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd267698(v=vs.110).aspx):

```
ListA.Zip(ListB, (a,b) => b + a.ToString());
```

This produces:

```
csharp> List<double> ListA = new List<double> {  1,  2,  3,  4,  5  };
csharp> List<string> ListB = new List<string> { "A","B","C","D","E" };
csharp> ListA.Zip(ListB, (a,b) => b + a.ToString());
{ "A1", "B2", "C3", "D4", "E5" }
```

`Zip` itererates over the two iterables concurrently and produces the product constructed by the function. From the moment one of the iterables is exhausted, the `Zip` stops.